# Error occured when CV Bridge compilation with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, ubuntu-14.04, ros

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.
I'm executing this command:

```
catkin_make -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so
```

However, the following error occurred when compiling CVbridge with Python 2.7:

```
Built target image_geometry
make[2]: *** No rule to make target /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so, needed by /home/kbad10/ros_catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv_bridge/boost/cv_bridge_boost.so'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/CMakeFiles/cv_bridge_boost.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Check below screenshots:

[image: Error screenshot]

[image: Overall process that is being performed]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Mick please check the question, I've updated it with more information

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install python development libraries. Install them using

> sudo apt-get install python-dev

If they are already installed try this commad -

> catkin_make -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python2 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE=/usr/include/python2.7 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lin/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so

Comment: Checked. The Python development libraries are already to the newest version.

Comment: Can you go to the lib folder and see if the file libpython2.7.so is present.

Comment: The libpython2.7.so is not present there, but I think it will be created by the command executed.

Comment: What files you get when you search libpython2.7 in /usr/lib

Comment: Here:
https://image.ibb.co/crPEoz/Screenshot_from_2018_08_02_21_13_06.png

Comment: @KhushalBadhan Can you search in /usr/lib by using the search command.

Comment: Here:
https://image.ibb.co/hyRSbK/Screenshot_from_2018_08_03_14_28_04.png

Comment: Can you get the location of the file ??

Comment: I think the libpython.so is in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/. If it is there then run **>sudo ln -s  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so**

Comment: Same problem is happening with this command:
`catkin_make -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python2`
There is no rule to make the following file target:
`/usr/bin/python2.7.so`
and I searched for the file in usr/bin folder the file present does not have .so extension

here: https://image.ibb.co/icTtYz/Screenshot_from_2018_08_03_18_34_14.png

Answer (score 0):

I Don't Know The Commit You cloned from the GitHub repo but there's merged pull request That Fixes the same problem u addressed [Here](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/pull/239).

Comment: @Shashikant Ghangare can you explain this answer?

Comment: There was a problem like the one you have and someone fixed it in the later versions of the code u downloaded

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem patch (edit) the file 'cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt' with patch in the following link:
https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/pull/239/commits/9a9ad348abdfed010c70604cd964786f22220b30